# Cannot read property 'Base' of undefined error using mocha-allure-reporter in Cypress

Tags: mocha.js, cypress, allure

I am trying to use [mocha-allure-reporter](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-mocha#readme) in [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/). I installed `mocha` and `mocha-allure-reporter` as dev dependencies and mentioned `mocha-allure-reporter` as the reporter in `cypress.json`.

I tried the below code quoted in the [example section of mocha allure page](https://github.com/allure-examples/mocha-allure-example/blob/master/test/simple.spec.js):

```
require('mocha-allure-reporter');

describe("simple test demo", () => {
  const testStep = allure.createStep("initial", () => {
    console.log("First Test")
  });

  it("simple passed test", () => {
    testStep();
  });
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Base' of undefined

...at the first line itself:

```
require('mocha-allure-reporter')
```

Upon looking on console, I see that the error is originated at line - `var Base = require("mocha").reporters.Base` in the Allure reporter :

```
var Base = require("mocha").reporters.Base;
var Allure = require("allure-js-commons");
...
...
global.allure = new Runtime(allureReporter);

/**
 * Initialize a new `Allure` test reporter.
 *
 * @param {Runner} runner
 * @param {Object} opts mocha options
 * @api public
 */
function AllureReporter(runner, opts) {
...
...
```

Please note that the following output xml file is getting created in the `allure-results` directory once the execution is done.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<ns2:test-suite xmlns:ns2='urn:model.allure.qatools.yandex.ru' start='1547481439243' stop='1547481439477'>
    <name></name>
    <title></title>
    <test-cases>
        <test-case start='1547481439282' status='broken' stop='1547481439460'>
            <name>An uncaught error was detected outside of a test</name>
            <title>An uncaught error was detected outside of a test</title>
            <labels/>
            <parameters/>
            <steps/>
            <attachments/>
            <failure>
                <message>Cannot read property 'Base' of undefined

                This error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

                When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

                Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

                We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.</message>
                <stack-trace>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Base' of undefined

                This error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

                When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

                Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

                We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.
                    at Object.&lt;anonymous> (http://localhost:61925/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Tests\Test.spec.js-289:15125:38)
                    at Object.98.allure-js-commons (http://localhost:61925/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Tests\Test.spec.js-289:15201:4)
                    at o (http://localhost:61925/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Tests\Test.spec.js-289:1:265)
                    at http://localhost:61925/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Tests\Test.spec.js-289:1:316
                    at Object.40.mocha-allure-reporter (http://localhost:61925/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Tests\Test.spec.js-289:7566:1)
                    at o (http://localhost:61925/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Tests\Test.spec.js-289:1:265)
                    at r (http://localhost:61925/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Tests\Test.spec.js-289:1:431)
                    at http://localhost:61925/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Tests\Test.spec.js-289:1:460</stack-trace>
            </failure>
        </test-case>
    </test-cases>
</ns2:test-suite>
```

Please guide me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use **mocha-allure-reporter** by simply installing it (along with mocha),

```js
npm install mocha mocha-allure-reporter
```

and setting up a script in `package.json`, following the Cypress guidelines for npm reporters [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters.html#npm-Reporters)

```js
"scripts": {
  ...
  "cypress:run": "cypress run --reporter mocha-allure-reporter"
```

Note, I think that these reporters only work with the Cypress 'run' command, not the Cypress 'open' command.

The output is a folder called 'allure-results' which contains a bunch of xml files. I presume these can then be displayed using the Allure framework tool.

Example output file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<ns2:test-suite xmlns:ns2='urn:model.allure.qatools.yandex.ru' start='1547254197911' stop='1547254201289'>
    <name>Tasks Page</name>
    <title>Tasks Page</title>
    <test-cases>
        <test-case start='1547254199721' status='passed' stop='1547254199815'>
            <name>should have a title</name>
            <title>should have a title</title>
            <labels/>
            <parameters/>
            <steps/>
            <attachments/>
        </test-case>
    </test-cases>
</ns2:test-suite>
```

---

### Run allure code in cy.task()

To run the allure code, you need to access the nodejs context through `cy.task`.

For example,

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
require('mocha-allure-reporter');

module.exports = (on) => {
  on('task', {
    allureTestStep () {
      const testStep = allure.createStep("initial", () => {
        console.log("First Test")
      });
      testStep()

      return null
    }
  })
}
```

**spec**

```js
describe("simple test demo", () => {

  it("simple passed test", () => {
    cy.task('allureTestStep')
  });
})
```

Note this produces the console log in the command window where you start Cypress, not the browser console.

However, you can pass a value back from the task into the test, depending on what you are actually trying to do (see docs for details).

Comment: I tried the same originally too and could see the xml files in allure-results directory as well. However, the test fails with the mentioned error (`Base Undefined`) at  `require('mocha-alure-reporter')` which is the first line in my spec file. Could you please try executing the mentioned spec file code.

Comment: Added more details to the question now to make my comment clear @eric99

Comment: I did not use `require('mocha-alure-reporter')` and got passing tests. You are probably over-thinking the problem, Cypress does all the requiring for you.

Comment: Tried it already. If I remove `require('mocha-allure-reporter')`, the next error is at line - `allure.createStep` which says `allure is not defined`.

Comment: My bad -  I didn't notice you were trying to use `allure.createStep`. What's the purpose of this?

Comment: Reason to use allure.createStep is to report the step in the allure results xml file. So I could see in the allure html reported generated out of the xml file. After trying the above code, I do see console log in the command window. However, it is not reported in the allure results xml file.

Comment: Command window displays: `allure-js-commons: Unexpected startStep() of initial. There is no parent step` First Test  
`allure-js-commons: Unexpected endStep(). There are no any steps running`

Comment: Test case with `name` and `title` labels having values - "simple passed test" are displayed in the allure results  xml file as expected. However test step related label is not displayed here

Comment: Your last two comments indicate a totally different problem - one related to Allure not to how Cypress can run allure code. The task mechanism solves the problem of where to run the Allure code.

Comment: Got it. Will create a new post for this issue. Thanks!